# Porting stored procedures between MySQL servers

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, porting

I have inherited a web-application project (PHP/MySQL) which makes extensive use of stored procedures, and I am unsure how to transfer these to my local machine for development.

Specifically, it is the exporting and importing of these stored procedures that I am facing difficulty with (with the ultimate aim of being able to automate installation of a "base" version of the application database, complete with stored procedures).

I shall state the bits and pieces that I believe I understand:

- I can export the `information_schema.ROUTINES` table, but cannot import it (phpMyAdmin) onto my local server (I believe that `information_schema` is a system database?)
- As I do not have shell/command-line access to the "online" MySQL servers, tools such as `mysqldump` are only of very limited use (to port to my local testing machine, but not vice versa)
- The command `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name;` is supposed to output SQL that can be used to create the procedure, but I can't seem to get this functioning correctly (`ERROR 1305 (42000): PROCEDURE delAddress does not exist`)
- Assuming that the the above works, the next step is to have it be looped to export all stored procedures (..and then be run via phpMyAdmin elsewhere, to import it)

Please correct anything that is incorrect, and provide guidance on how to automate porting between database servers.

Many thanks

Comment: Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere btw - I have been searching around and there is a lot of information around that may/may not work, I just don't have quite enough a grasp on this to fully understand what is relevant and useful just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was ridiculously simple.

On the export page, there is an `Add CREATE PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT statement` option.

By checking this box, it also exports the SQL necessary to import procedures at a later date/on another server.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL Workbench's migration feature. The whole thing is free and it does an amazing job.